# iOS QuickType bar: Add custom suggestion

Tags: ios, ios8

I want to add custom suggestions based on my app's user (e.g. let's say if it is a game then based on users he interacted with).

Ideally those suggestions should be displayed while the input field is still empty.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Hey! Do you have any updates?