# crash using ACEAutocompleteBar in swift:

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I followed the instructions in [Customizing QuickType Suggestions in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167416/customizing-quicktype-suggestions-in-ios/35511249#35511249).
 I get a crash with error

> setAutocompleteWithDataSource:delegate:customize:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7fe8c981bc00'

The relevant code is simply:

```
@IBOutlet weak var brand: UITextField! 

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    . . .
    self.brand.setAutocompleteWith(self, delegate: self, customize: { inputView in
            inputView?.isHidden = false
        })
}
```

I'm using Xcode 9.1, and swift 3.  I don't grok the syntax for closures when used with objective C.  Can you see my error?

Note that I added the context of the call to setAutocompleteWith. Is viewDidLoad() a good place do do the call?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't type the function name properly.

Try this instead:

```
@IBOutlet weak var brand: UITextField! 

self.brand.setAutocompleteWithDataSource(self, delegate: self, customize: { inputView in
            inputView?.isHidden = false
        })
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I try that, Xcode tells me:
`setAutocompleteWithDataSource(_:delegate:customize:)' has been renamed to 'setAutocompleteWith(_:delegate:customize:)'`